# Multi-output regression python

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.x

I am new to machine learning and cannot figure a way to solve this problem:

I have X which is always one row/record while the y can be a row or more.

Here is a simple sample from my data-set, 'i mean that i have more columns in both x and y that the presented here'

```
x = [[1,3,'John'],[3,5,'Sandra'],[5,2,'Leila']]
y =[

[['D',3,,'K'],['JK',8,'GH']],

[['FG',6,'DF'],['WE',4,'EF'],['CV',5,'EE']],

[['TG',9,'CB']],

]
```

y contains both numerical and categorical values, all the rows in y need to predicted.

I am using python to do Multi-output regression

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? What do the values in the result-vectors represent? Do they describe positions in the same space or is this just a summary of independent variables? Also, why is there a varying number of rows? Simply describing your use-case and the variables should be enough, I guess.